# How to create a void matrix (not filled with ones or zeros) in Python of expected dimensions M times N?

Tags: python, vector, matrix, dimension

In order to create a void vector a of N elements in Python we use:

```
a = [None] * N
```

How about creating a matrix of M times N not filled with ones or zeros?
thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a more "matrixy" answer is to use numpy's `object` dtype: for example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.ndarray(shape=(5,6), dtype=np.object)
array([[None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

But, as wim suggests, this might be inefficient, if you're using this to do math.

```
>>> mat = np.empty(shape=(5,6))
>>> mat.fill(np.nan)
>>> mat
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
>>>
```

If you're really using more python objecty things, and don't intend to fill the matrix, you can use something nicer; a `dict`!

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mat = defaultdict(lambda: None)
>>> mat[4,4]
>>> mat[4,4] is None
True
```

Comment: but I need more than 5 or 6 elements! :\

Comment: replace `shape=(...)` with the size you want.  you can use any size you like!

Comment: If you plan to use numbers in the array, it probably makes more sense to use `np.nan` than None / dtype=object.  And if you "don't care" what the values are, use np.empty.

Comment: Yes! it was a stupidity to post the previous comment! I didn't take the time to see carefully! Thank you @IfLoop for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
matrix = [[None]*N for _ in xrange(M)]
```

Don't do `[[None]*N]*M`, or you'll get a list whose `M` elements are all really the same list object.

Note that this isn't really a matrix; it's a list of lists. Trying to do something like `max(matrix)` won't work right, and if you ever try to make the elements of your matrix be lists, it won't be possible to distinguish whether your data structure is supposed to be a matrix of lists, a list of matrices, or a 3D matrix. If you want to do a lot of matrix operations, [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) is highly recommended. It offers actual matrices and arbitrary-dimension arrays with high performance and very convenient syntax.

Comment: Thank you @user2357112 for your powerful answer! Unfortunately I can't accept an answer in 6 minutes!

Answer (score 2):

```
matrix = []
for i in xrange(M):
    matrix.append([None]*N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has an [empty](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) ndarray creation method

```
numpy.empty(shape, dtype, order)
```

for matrices [matlib.empty](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matlib.empty.html#numpy.matlib.empty):

```
numpy.matlib.empty(shape, dtype, order)
```